# Expression Engine Channel Images

Tags: expressionengine

I've migrated an old site built using Expression Engine and a series of images have dropped out. All these images have a dynamically generated path which appears to come from a "Channel Images" plugin, like so:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/?ACT=39&key=YTo0OntzOjg6ImltYWdlX2lkIjtzOjQ6IjMzMTYiO3M6NDoic2l6ZSI7czo1OiJzbWFsbCI7czo0OiJ0aW1lIjtpOjE0MzA4MTY2MjA7czoyOiJpcCI7czoxMDoiNzkuNzguNi4zNyI7fQ==" />
```

I assumed it may be similar to the Wordpress guid issue, perhaps a find/replace in the database to update paths? I can't find any config files for the plugin and EE's paths are set ok for the server, so if anyone has used this plugin and can assist please let me know!

Thanks in advance,
Graham

Comment: Is this it: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/channel-images

Comment: That's the one! I've tried clearing caches etc but no luck yet :(

Answer (score 2):

Can you check the exp_actions table and make sure there is an entry with the ID 39? If that's not the case then something went wrong during the installation of the module Channel Images.

Comment: ID 39 is indeed missing - did it perhaps break during the migration? Do you happen to know of a fix - even manually entering the id back in?

Comment: I'd drop the exp_actions table and re-import it. Also, make sure that the order of the rows matches the one from your previous installs.